# TypeGuard: Check between two different interfaces

Tags: typescript

I have two different interfaces. I would like to write a typeguard that checks if the incoming object is of type A or type B.

```
interface A {
  foo: string
}

interface B {
  bar: string
}


function isA(test: A | B): test is A {
  return test.foo !== undefined
}
```

This code does not work however. `Error: Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'A | B'. Property 'foo' does not exist on type 'B'`

Is it possible to write a typeguard for an object that might be of both types?

Comment: You can just write `"foo" in test` as your type guard, or something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wX1gDN) if you want to keep your `isA` function and eliminate the possibility of some subtype of `B` with a `foo` of non-`string` type.